# How to use dataframes from loophole result in R

Tags: r, loops, assign, r-rownames

By assigning date_[c], I have 35 "date_c"'s(below code).

```
for (c in 1:nrow(datetable2)) {
   assign(paste("date_",c,sep=""),dt2[which(dt2$Date==datetable2$Date[c]),])
  
 }
```

Now, I want to change each "date_c"'s rownames to 1:length(date_c). I used the code below but it doesn't work. The program says it can not find "date_[d]". How should I change the "date_[d]" issue in the below loophole?

```
for (d in 1:nrow(datetable2)){
  rownames(date_[d]) <-  seq(length=nrow(date_[d]))
}
```

Comment: You should avoid `assign()`. It would be easier if you just stored all your data.frames in a list. Then you could apply any function you like to that list. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames

Comment: Got it Thanx. @MrFlick

Answer (score 0):

Get all the `date_c` daatframes in a list, use `lapply` to iterate over it and remove the rownames. When we remove the rownames it actually recreates the rownames from `1:nrow(data)`.

```
result <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'date_')), function(x) 
                 {rownames(x) <- NULL;x})
```

`result` would have a list of dataframes with the rownames as we want. It is better to keep data in a list as it is easier to manage them. If you still want the changes to reflect in the original dataframe you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```